# Access RSA key container

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rsa

I have generated a RSA key using aspnet_regiis.exe and installed it on a target machine. How do I access it using C# code?

I want it of type `System.Security.Cryptography.RSA`.

I will update the question, when I figure out. In the meantime, any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *key* to select a specific container is to create [`CspParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cspparameters.aspx) instance and use it when creating your `RSACryptoServiceProvider`.

The difficulty is to set the right parameters. You might have to delve into older CryptoAPI documentation to find every flags (unless MSDN documentation got a lot better in the last years).